# lm function on 1min xts time series

Tags: r, xts, lm

I am wondering whether the linear regression function `lm` should fully work on time series of 1 minute interval. I would expect yes, but seemingly not in this case. I have got the following xts time series `z`

```
                         mean
    2016-03-11 08:37:00  10
    2016-03-11 08:38:00  11
    2016-03-11 08:39:00  12
```

Applying  `lm( z ~ index(z) )` gives

```
Coefficients:
(Intercept)     index(z)  
         11           NA
```

So the slope of the regression is NA. I wonder why? I don't see any mathematical reason why this couldn't be calculated.

If I change the time of the first row to have a 5 min interval, so `z` equals

```
                      mean
2016-03-11 08:33:00   10
2016-03-11 08:38:00   11
2016-03-11 08:39:00   12
```

then  `lm( z ~ index(z) )` works as expected and returns a slope of 4.839e-3

```
Coefficients:
(Intercept)     index(z)  
 -7.053e+06    4.839e-03
```

Do I misunderstand anything about how the `lm` function should work? Or can anybody comment on this behaviour? Is there any other function which can calculate the slope for 1min series?

Comment: good question! Do you have any reproducible example to work with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't specific to xts or the `lm` function. It's an issue with estimating linear regression coefficients in general. You can't estimate variation in a data series using data that effectively does not vary (within floating point arithmetic precision).

You can see that your first example is computationally singular:

```
lm(z ~ index(z), singular.ok=FALSE)
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  singular fit encountered
```

But it would "work" if you lower the tolerance, but that sacrifices numerical stability.

```
lm(z ~ index(z), singular.ok=FALSE, tol=1e-8)

Call:
lm(formula = z ~ index(z), singular.ok = FALSE, tol = 1e-08)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)     index(z)  
 -2.430e+07    1.667e-02
```

Your second example works because you created enough variation.

Comment: Thank you, lowering the tolerance solves my issue and works fine for me. I just want to know the slope of these points, which come frome another regression calculation, thus should be sufficiently significant. But I guess I should also read more about the mathematical background.

Comment: Joshua, would scaling up the index beforehand, give the same result as setting `tol`? E.g. `ix <- as.numeric(index(z))*10;lm(z ~ ix)`  (and scale the `ix` coefficient afterwards, to compensate).

Comment: @DarrenCook: Yes, that should work. If you run into this issue a lot, it might be worth using a package that supports higher precision when estimating linear models. I don't know of any, but I would be surprised if one did not exist.